# What would be more compact/clean way to parse a "value=1234; some other thing" in kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin

If I have a string with a bunch of tokens that are in the "key=value" form.

For instance "something variable=1234 some other thing"

What would be the most compact and easier way to parse this in kotlin, considering that the name of the key/variable is known and the type of the value is an Int?

(I'm thinking at something similar to scanf() in C)

Comment: do you want to parse it from a JSONObject?

Comment: Not particularly from JSONObject in this case. It is more of a rhetorical question.

Answer (score 1):

What about something as simple as this?

```
  val vars = "hello, world! variable=1234 Today the sun shines variable1=5678 bright".
      split(' ').
      filter { it.contains('=') }.
      map { it.split('=')}.
      map { Pair(it[0], Integer.parseInt(it[1]))}

  println(vars)
```

`vars` is a list of pairs (string, integer). Prints:

```
[(variable, 1234), (variable1, 5678)]
```